# HoloLens BLE communication ( windows 10 )

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-10, bluetooth-lowenergy, hololens

I want to have two sensors, one in each hand to give out position values to the HoloLens Unity3D app.
these two sensors are temporarily going to be android native application on android phones sending out some random values in BLE.

I just thought since HoloLens supports BLE, It should be possible for the holoLens to connect and receive the values advertised by the sensors.
But I could not find any plugin in Unity3D asset store for windows BLE. I need to know if anyone has impletemented any samples plugins for windows BLE in Unity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Currently, Microsoft HoloLens only supports BLE mouses and keyboards** (See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12636/hololens-pair-bluetooth-devices), so you will not be able to connect other devices through Bluetooth unless you hack their interfaces (Victor Cazacov's suggestion).

The current alternative is to connect your sensors with HoloLens through a different interface, mostly likely sockets over WiFi. For instance, I have connected Bluetooth sensors, HTC Vive Controllers, and Leap Motion to HoloLens through UDP Sockets. The downside is that you might need a computer to receive the data from these devices and then send it over to HoloLens.

Answer (score -1):

If you can make your sensor pretend be a Bluetooth keyboard or a mouse for the HoloLens, then you can just use standard Unity libraries:

```
if (UnityEngine.Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
{
    // moved left
    ...
}
```

[Here is an example](https://github.com/cazacov/HoloControl) how to connect Wii Nunchuk (2D joystick, two buttons) to the HoloLens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my project needs more of actual hand position values that needs to be sent from a gyro in hand. I was actually looking for some Windows client BLE plugin / sample in Unity3D