# Bluetooth LE Advertisement watcher not receiving on HoloLens 2

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, hololens

Following on from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67438377/bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher-no-events-on-hololens), I'm also having trouble getting a Bluetooth watcher to receive advertisements on HoloLens 2. I've run through the example [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement) with no luck running scenario 2 on my laptop and scenario 1 on my HoloLens.

My HoloLens does not appear to be triggering any received events. I've tried restarting the HoloLens and checking for updates. I'm currently running OS build 20346.1403.

Would greatly appreciate any help troubleshooting. I have been able to get the [regular BluetoothLE sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/BluetoothLE) to run correctly, however my eventual goal is to get all this to run from within a Unity application and again for some reason the watcher isn't receiving any events with the regular BluetoothLE code from my Unity application.

If anyone has experience with Unity and bluetoothLE examples I'd very much like to learn more about it.

```
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
#if WINDOWS_UWP
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
#endif

public class GPSReceiver : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI debugText;
#if WINDOWS_UWP
    BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher;
#endif
    public static ushort BEACON_ID = 1775;
    public EventProcessor eventProcessor;

void Awake()
{
#if WINDOWS_UWP
    watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
    BluetoothLEManufacturerData manufacturerData = new BluetoothLEManufacturerData
    {
        CompanyId = BEACON_ID
    };
    watcher.AdvertisementFilter.Advertisement.ManufacturerData.Add(manufacturerData);
    watcher.Received += Watcher_Received;
    watcher.Start();
    debugText.text = "Watcher status: " + watcher.Status.ToString() + " " + watcher.ScanningMode.ToString();
#endif
}

#if WINDOWS_UWP
private async void Watcher_Received(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    debugText.text = "received bytes";
    ushort identifier = args.Advertisement.ManufacturerData[0].CompanyId;
    byte[] data = args.Advertisement.ManufacturerData[0].Data.ToArray();
    // Updates to Unity UI don't seem to work nicely from this callback so just store a reference to the data for later processing.
    eventProcessor.QueueData(data);
}
#endif
}
```

Comment: Is there any other device in your network environment that can test and verify the communication reliability of the publisher in the line with expectations?  Please feel free to feedback.

Comment: Thanks @Hernando-MSFT, I was able to get the BTLE Advertising demo to work between laptop and HL2, at least with a foreground publisher and a background watcher. 

I'm still stuck getting Unity to play well with getting watcher.received events to fire. Bluetooth capabilities are checked and it appears to start the watcher correctly. I'm pretty much trying to recreate what that previous question by Dijkstra18 was doing, but I'm not sure how reinstalling apps/the OS would help?

Comment: It's perhaps something wrong with your Unity code. Could you provide more information about your issue and developing environment? Such as the version number of your Unity, and the detailed steps and MVCE (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for reproducing.

Comment: @Hernando-MSFT sorry for the late response. I've added my code that should be watching for the advertisement and have a debug text to let me know if bytes are being received. I'm running Unity 2019.4.11f1. I've double checked that Bluetooth is set correctly in the capabilities in both Unity and the package manifest.

Comment: So, on your laptop side, are you still using the BTLE Advertising demo for testing? I noticed that the `CompanyId` property is customized in your unity code. If you are running the BTLE Advertising demo on your laptop, please make sure that the `CompanyId` of the two is the same.

Comment: Ok, finally got things working and the answer lay in a comment on the previous question by Dijkstra18. It wasn't obvious and it won't be again in just a comment, so I'm going to write a blog post on it (I'll post the link here soon) and outline what I've learned. Hopefully no one has to go through this trouble again.... until the next HL!